# MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#update

Tags: ruby

```
<div id="error_explanation">


  <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>

  <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>


    <li><%= msg %></li>


  <% end %>


  </ul>


</div>
```

```
<%= f.label :name %><br />


<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

```
<%= f.label :email %><br />


<%= f.text_field :email %>
```

```
<%= f.label :password %><br />


<%= f.text_field :password %>
```

```
<%= f.label :confirm_password %><br />


<%= f.text_field :confirm_password %>
```

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

I got stucked up....

I think this is the code you are asking for.....

Please go through this and let me know if any corrections needed to be made...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog which help you to understand 'MassAssignmentSecurity::Error' and to solve it:
[Click here](http://happybearsoftware.com/how-i-avoid-the-rails-mass-assignment-security-mistake.html)